# plotting a series of coordinates stored in a 2D array

Tags: julia, julia-plots

So let's say I define the following array in Julia:

```
M=[[1,1],[2,4],[3,9],[4,16],[5,25],[6,36],[7,49],[8,64],[9,81],[10,100],[11,121],[12,144]]
```

Clearly each element `[x,y]` follows the quadratic rule $y=x^2$ and so I expect to get a parabolic shape when I plot it by using the command `plot(M)`.

But instead I'm getting something like this:
[image]

What am I doing wrong, and what should I do to get my desired result -- a parabolic shape?

Answer (score 5):

From the [docs for Plots.jl](https://docs.juliaplots.org/stable/input_data/#Inputs-are-arguments,-not-keywords):

> The plot function has several methods:
> plot(y): treats the input as values for the y-axis and yields a unit-range as x-values.

i.e. when you pass a single argument to `plot`, the values in the argument get interpreted as **y-axis** values, with the x-axis being `1, 2, 3, ...`.
Here, because `M` is a vector of vectors, a line plot is created for each of the inner vectors. For example, `[3, 9]` results in a line plot from `(1, 3)` to `(1, 9)`.

To plot the parabola, in this case, you can do:

```
plot(first.(M), last.(M))
```

which will extract each first element of the inner array to form the x-axis, and each second element for the y-axis.

[image: Parabolic curve]

Of course, it's better to just create them as separate vectors in the first place, if you don't require `M` to be a vector of vectors for some other reason.

---

In case `M` is changed into a `Matrix` instead (which is the recommended way to create 2D arrays in Julia), for eg.

```
julia> M
12×2 Matrix{Int64}:
  1    1
  2    4
  3    9
etc.
```

then you can plot it with

```
julia> @views plot(M[:, 1], M[:, 2])
```

`M[:, 1]` gets all values on the first column (the x-axis), `M[:, 2]` the same on the second column (y-axis), and the `@views` at the beginning avoids these being allocated a new memory area unnecessarily, instead being read and used directly from `M` itself.

Comment: thanks for this. The actual 2D array I'm trying to play has 1000+ elements, and are generated by a different step in my project. Your answer is much more useful than if I manually create separate vectors for them. At least I think so, then again, I'm new to this. Thanks again!

Comment: Makes sense. However, keep in mind that Julia has an actual `Matrix` type, and an array of arrays is not the same thing as a 2D array in Julia. If the code that's creating `M` is also yours, strongly consider changing it to create a `Matrix` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, since Plots handles an array of Tuples as an array of (x, y) points, this works:

```
plot(Tuple.(M))
```

[image]